# Debug Go program with GDB on macOS

Tags: go, gdb

A simple Go program, say `main.go`:

```
package main

func main() {
    println("hello, world!")
}
```

Then build with

```
go build -gcflags "-N -l" -o main main.go
```

Using GDB:

```
$ gdb main
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2
(...)
Reading symbols from main...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loading Go Runtime support.
(gdb) source /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
Loading Go Runtime support.
(gdb) info files
Symbols from "/Users/changkun/Desktop/demo/main".
Local exec file:
        `/Users/changkun/Desktop/demo/main', file type mach-o-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x1049e20
        0x0000000001001000 - 0x000000000104dfcf is .text
        0x000000000104dfe0 - 0x0000000001077344 is __TEXT.__rodata
        (...)
(gdb) b *0x1049e20
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1049e20
(gdb)
```

There is no `at` in the GDB outputs, the version of Go is `go version go1.11 darwin/amd64` and:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin | grep go
lrwxr-xr-x    1 changkun  admin        24 Aug 25 16:37 go -> ../Cellar/go/1.11/bin/go
```

======

Same process in linux environment:

```
docker run -itd --name golang golang:1.11
docker exec -it golang bash
```

then entering container install `gdb`

```
root@1326d3f1a957:/# gdb main
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
(...)
(gdb) info files
Symbols from "/main".
Local exec file:
        `/main', file type elf64-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x44a2e0
        0x0000000000401000 - 0x000000000044ea8f is .text
        (...)
(gdb) b *0x44a2e0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x44a2e0: file /usr/local/go/src/runtime/rt0_linux_amd64.s, line 8.
(gdb)
```

Linux is able to show `(gdb) b *0x44a2e0
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x44a2e0: file /usr/local/go/src/runtime/rt0_linux_amd64.s, line 8.`

What did I miss in macOS? How can I debug and trace the program on macOS?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  You wish to do debugging at a low level, using gdb with go binaries.  This might be useful https://golang.org/doc/gdb

Comment: @Vorsprung the document doesn't address the problem here. You see, debugging on Linux works fine and it is able to show everything with the breakpoint. However  on macOS, nothing appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Go 1.11, the debug information is compressed for purpose of reduce binary size, and gdb on the Mac does not understand compressed DWARF.

The workaround is to also specify `-ldflags=-compressdwarf=false` which does exactly what it claims.

To do this generally:

```
export GOFLAGS="-ldflags=-compressdwarf=false"
```

See discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/LlgN1qpbRE8